# React Editable PDF options (React-pdf/js-pdf)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, pdf, react-pdf

I am not sure if I am looking at the best package for my use case, or how other businesses are doing it. But I am looking to embedded a editable PDF inside of a page, allow a  user to fill out the PDF and then click submit and I will save the PDF on my server.

Very similar to how DocUSign works.

I found with react=pdf or js-pdf I could possibly do something like this but still does not look entirely possible. These libraries allow me to customize a custom PDF and add my own fields, but most of these documents already have these fields in place.

Here is an example one: http://site.petitrc.com/setup/associated/setupb6.1/B6.2_EditableSetupSheet.pdf

Is there any other packages similar to this, or ways I could make react-pdf work possibly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm also interested.